# Set up route to target the named <router-outlet> from component's template, not from AppComponent's template

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular7, router-outlet

### Motivation

I need multiple layout templates in my Angular application: an empty template for authentication related components, a template with a menu-bar for application-specific navigation and a template that adds a sidebar to the menu-bar. It would be helpful to have the sidebar as a named router outlet.

Here's a demonstration/simplification of the problem: Assuming `TwoOutletsComponent` has a `<router-outlet name="seconde" />` named router, I would like this link: `/two/one(second:forsecond)` to load my `TwoOutletsComponent`, load some content in the unnamed router, then load `/forsecond` in the "second" named router-outlet. When activating that link the DOM should logically look something like this:

```
<AppComponent>
  <AppComponent's router-outlet>    
    <TwoOutletsComponent>
      <router-outlet named="sidebar>[content from /forsecond]</router-outlet>
      <router-outlet>[content from /two/one]</router-outlet>
    <TwoOutletsComponent>
```

Given the logical-view above, I can get the `/two/one` content to load just fine in the unnamed router-outlet, but the content from `/forsecond` doesn't show; No errors are shown in the Console and enabling Router tracing shows that the `/forsecond` route is resolved just fine.

If on the other hand I'd put a `<router-outlet name="second" />` in AppComponent then the `/forsecond` would load just fine - just not where I want it! The logical view in that case would look something like this:

```
<AppComponent> / <-- this gets loaded by default
  <AppComponent's router-outlet>    
    <TwoOutletsComponent>
      <router-outlet>[content from /two/one]</router-outlet>
    <TwoOutletsComponent>
  <AppComponent's second router-outlet>[content from /foresecond]</router-outlet>
```

My relevant routes would look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { ... other routes not included },
  {
    path: "two", component: TwoOutletsComponent,
    children: [      
      { path: "one", component: PlainTextComponent }
    ]
  },
  { 
    path: "forsecond", 
    pathMatch: "full", 
    component: PlainTextComponent, 
    outlet: "second" 
  }
]
```

### What I think is happening:

I think Angular's Router is treating all routes, including the secondary routes, in a context-free way. If it does that it makes sens to look for the "second" router-outlet in AppComponent's template. I was hoping to somehow tip-in the Router that the target router-outlet is to be found in the TwoOutletsComponent's template, not in AppComponent's template.

In my attempts to tip-in the router I tried to mimic the Route used for the main content in order but the result was the same, no content shown:

I've set up a Stackblitz to hopefuly make this clear:
[link to Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-named-router-outlet-in-component)

Answer (score 0):

I've tracked down this issue to what I think is a bug in the way the Angular Router finds the named outlet: even those the Router constructs a tree-like structure with the complete hierarchy of the current view, the named outlet is only searched at the *first* level. I think this is a bug, I think the Router should follow the "primary" outlet and recursively search for the correctly named outlet.

I've submitted a fix on github; If it gets accepted (confirming this is indeed a bug and not a "feature") I'll delete the question. If it doesn't get accepted I'll keep the question (and revise this answer).

https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/27262